# ACTION_WEB_SEARCH opens the right search query for the first time only

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app which opens the ACTION_WEB_SEARCH intent to open the search app. It works fine the first time, but if the activity is started again, the search parameters don't change.

```
public static void launchWebSearch(Context context, String query) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The above code will open the google search app with the query in it for the first time. Next time its invoked, it will still open the google search app but the query won't change and will still have the old search results.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. What version are you testing on?

Comment: Android 4.4.2 (Galaxy Note 3 ATT)

Comment: Its actually happening of the Google Search app is open.. it just switches to it instead of actually searching for the passed query.

Comment: Make sure that the `strQuery` variable is `public` and not `static.` Otherwise, the variable change is not saved when the new intent is started.

Comment: strQuery is not static, but its passed in a static method (updated the question)

Comment: Should anything to do with the context affect this? The actual method that calls launchWebSearch is in the onClick handler of a listview cursor adapter. So, MyActivity -> MyFragment (saves an instance of MyActivity from onAttach) -> CursorAdapter (passes MyActivity as context) -> onClick (uses the instance of myActivity that was called when this was initialized) -> launchWebSearch

Comment: I would try and make the method containing the strQuery variable non-static. In statically typed languages such as Java, static methods are called "static" because they are resolved statically (i.e. at compile time) based on the class they are called on and not dynamically as in the case with instance methods which are resolved polymorphically based on the runtime type of the object. Therefore, static methods cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your error either; I suspect the problem may be somewhere else in your code.

Just a shot in the dark but you may want to try adding the following flag to your intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: Didn't work :(. Will keep looking - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I believe could cause this is an incorrect implementation of the activity that handles the `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` intent (such as being declared as `singleInstance` or `singleTop` and not implementing `onNewIntent()`). Possibly Samsung devices ship with a customized version of the search app?

I would suggest using `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` to see if there are any other possible matches for `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`.

Comment: I printed all the intentActivities, it only has google search: [ResolveInfo{4462bf30 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.google.GoogleSearch m=0x108000}]

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem,

After some digging, i discovered that uninstalling the update from "Google Search" fixed the problem, so this is indeed related to Google Now (Google Quicksearch, the stock version, works perfectly).

I fixed it by adding the following flags to my search intent:

```
    Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    // In the latest Google Now version, ACTION_WEB_SEARCH is broken when used with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
    // Adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK seems to fix the problem.
    search.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    search.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```